# Join mysql query results to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to generate a table list from data held in 2 tables.  One table is called PrimaryEvents and some sample data looks like:

```
|id|event   |validity|eventsrequired
|1 |event1  |7       |10
|1 |event2  |25      |1
|1 |event3  |12      |50
```

id here is just the user id of whoever created the data.

The second table is called portfolio, some sample data looks like:

```
|id|name    |number|datacompleted
|21|event1  |3     |2014-07-07
|15|event1  |5     |2014-07-05
|21|event2  |5     |2014-05-08
|15|event1  |1     |2013-05-05
|15|event1  |1     |2014-05-05
|21|event1  |13    |2014-08-07
|21|event1  |6     |2014-07-08
```

id here is the id of the user that has completed the event.

I have a query that populates an array to allow a table to be shown to the user, the table shows a list of ALL the events from PrimaryEvents with a left join of data from portfolio if they have completed an event by the same name.

I would like to change the functionality slightly to allow for the following:
Only events that are within the validity period date range are merged, AND the merged data automatically SUMs the number (from portfolio.number).

I am not sure how to progress this really.  Currently, I have managed to extract the data range using the following code:

```
$currentDate = DATE("Y-m-d");

$eventList = query("SELECT event,validity FROM PrimaryEvents ORDER BY event");

foreach ($eventList as $row)
    {
    //
    $event["validity"] = $row["validity"];
    $validityDate = Date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-". $row["validity"] . "days"));
    $eventsDateValidCompleted = query("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE id = ? AND datecompleted BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY name", $_SESSION["id"], $validityDate , $currentDate);
    }
```

What I am missing is how to do something useful with the daterange sorted array data.

Questions:
1) How can I SUM the event data within the valid date range (IE returned in $eventsDateValidCompleted array)?

2) How can I LEFT JOIN this array of data to each line of my current query?

```
    $allEvents = query("SELECT * FROM PrimaryEvents LEFT JOIN portfolio ON (PrimaryEvents.event = portfolio.name) WHERE PrimaryEvents.role = ? AND (portfolio.id = ? Or portfolio.id is null) ORDER BY PrimaryEvents.event", $currentRole, $_SESSION["id"]);
```

3) Is there a better way to make this happen?

Thanks for any help that can be offered on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum values from a query in MySQL using the SUM() function along with a GROUP BY clause. For example if you wanted to know the sum of all relevant portfolio.number values for a given user id and date range you could change this line:

```
$eventsDateValidCompleted = query("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE id = ? AND datecompleted BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY name", $_SESSION["id"], $validityDate , $currentDate);
```

to this:

```
$eventsDateValidCompleted = query("SELECT SUM(number) AS total_number FROM portfolio WHERE id = ? AND datecompleted BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY id", $_SESSION["id"], $validityDate , $currentDate);
```

And if you wanted to get this sum value by event, and as part of the original query you could do something like this:

```
SELECT e.event,e.validity, SUM(p.number) AS total_number
FROM PrimaryEvents e 
LEFT JOIN portfolio p ON p.name = e.event
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.event
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will give this a try tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Could you provide some amplification on how to use the second piece of code you posted?  I would like to be able to run the query and then sum the number of events returned with the date range.

Comment: If you need to know the number of rows returned by a query, take a look at `mysql_num_rows`. Of course you could also run a count query directly, which is accomplished by replacing your `SELECT` parameters with `COUNT(*)`. HTH.

Comment: Sorry, I am still slightly confused.  Run my code as posted above, then within my current foreach loop add the new SELECT query you posted above to do the sum work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but I suggest using SQL `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` along these lines:

```
SELECT pe.id, pe.event, sum(p.number) FROM PrimaryEvents pe
LEFT JOIN portfolio p ON (pe.event = p.name) AND p.id = pe.role AND p.datecompleted BETWEEN ? AND ?
WHERE pe.role = ? 
GROUP BY pe.id, pe.event
```

But, as I said, your (reduced) data model and the queries are not quite consistent, which is why I cannot tell if the above will do anything for you.